# How, and how often should I clean a freezer?

Tags: cleaning, refrigerator

My fridge/freezer has been turned on and running since I last moved house several years ago.  I clean the shelves/bins in the fridge every couple of months, or when something is spilled, but the freezer hasn't been cleaned for ages.   It doesn't particularly smell bad and it's not iced up, but there is a bit of that 'freezer smell'.

Should I clean it?

Is there any worthwhile cleaning procedure other than removing all the food and letting it come up to room temperature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't usually bother letting it warm up.  I just use a mixture of a mild kitchen cleaner and warm water on a paper towel.  If you're careful, and don't let any moisture pool up, it seems to evaporate before it freezes to the inside.

If you're just trying to combat a smell, try putting some baking soda in there.

As for how often to clean, I usually do a purge of the contents of the freeze 1-2 times a year, and do the cleaning then.